# Socket.io event not firing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is the full code :-
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0;     width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chatIN', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
socket.on('chatOUT', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append('<li><span>'+msg+'</span></li>');
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chatIN', function(msg){
        console.log('message:'+ msg);
        socket.emit('chatOUT:'+ msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am facing a problem while trying out a socket.io beginner's tutorial, I followed this tutorial 
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Everything seems to be okay till the very last thing, when they build a chat app, and when you hit submit in textbox, it updates the contents of the  element.

I can see the messages getting printed in the node js console, but nothing in chrome's console. I also tried debugging it using developer options, but the control just never goes in this method in the index.html.

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
```

Can someone please help ? I am really new to socket.io and nodejs.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide more of your code. There isn't much information to help you with here...

Comment: Here is my code
https://github.com/mithuns/my_node_app/tree/TestBranch

Comment: @MithunS - On this site, your code MUST be pasted into your question, not only referenced via an external link.  This is because external links have a nasty habit of changing over time or disappearing, thus ruining the value of the question as a reference for those who come in the future.  So, please paste the relevant portions of your code directly into your question and format it appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the wrong message from the server.

On the server, change this:

```
socket.emit('chatOUT:'+ msg);
```

to this:

```
socket.emit('chatOUT', msg);
```

Your client code is listening for the `chatOUT` message so that's the exact message name need to send.  Here's the matching client code:

```
socket.on('chatOUT', function(msg){...}
```